# PHP - Any way to access namespaced array keys without looping?

Tags: php, associative-array, key-value, get-meta-tags

**The Setup**

This is to do specifically with [Twitter Cards](https://www.shopify.ca/blog/12915741-everything-you-need-to-know-about-twitter-cards-for-ecommerce?rodeo_token=d7419e35-77ce-4861-8896-31767c71c38a), but I'm looking for a more general (i.e. not Twitter Cards specific) solution, as many meta tags are namespaced.

Twitter cards are stored in the head of a web page, inside `meta` tags. Something like...

```
<meta name="twitter:site" content="... tag content ...">
```

When you run [`get_meta_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php) on a website that uses the cards, you'll get a return that looks something like...

```
[
    ... bunch of other meta tags ...

    "twitter:card" : "... tag content ...",
    "twitter:description" : "... tag content ...",
    "twitter:title" : "... tag content ...",
    "twitter:site" : "... tag content ...",
    "twitter:image" : "... tag content ...",
    "twitter:creator" : "... tag content ...",

    ... maybe some more tags ...
]
```

All the keys that have to do with the Twitter Card are *namespaced* - what I mean is that each of them is prefaced with `twitter:`.

Even if a page has Twitter Card tags present, not all the tags listed above will necessarily be there. Some times it's all of them, some times it's just a couple.

**The Problem**

Let's get us some meta tags...

```
$tagsList = @get_meta_tags($url);
```

Because you don't know *for sure* which tags will be present, it doesn't make sense to test for them all...

```
if(isset($tagsList['twitter:card'])) {
    // Do something
}

if(isset($tagsList['twitter:description'])) {
    // Do something
}

... and so on ...
```

This approach is also particularly ineffective if you do not know *every* possible tag name that could be present, or Twitter decides to change the current standard.

So instead, you loop through every tag...

```
$twitterList = array();

foreach($tagsList as $tagName => $tagCont) {

    if(strpos(strtolower($tagName), 'twitter:') === 0) {

        // root = 'twitter', sub = 'card' or 'description' or ...
        list($root, $sub) = explode(':', $tagName);

        $twitterList[] = array(
            'root' => $root,   // Don't really need this
            'sub' => $sub, 
            'content' => $tagCont
        );

    }

}
```

And this works a treat. It's accurate, and returns your Twitter Card tags in a nice list. But, if I only need the tags pertaining to the Twitter Card, why the heck should I have to busy myself with looping through ALL of them!?

**The Question**

Is there a quick way to access these namespaced keys, without looping through every meta tag that was returned from the page? I'm only interested in the `twitter:` ones, so I don't want to waste resources and time looping through every tag.

Something like...

```
$twitterTags = $tagsList['twitter:'];
```

where the output would be along the lines of...

```
$twitterTags : [
    'card' : 'card content', 
    'description' : 'desc content', 
    ... and so on ...
]
```

I reckon you might be able to use [`array_map()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_map.asp), which *might* shorten the number of lines of code used, but you still end up looping through every key.

**Ok, I know it isn't necessarily necessary, but...**

Unless a page has an unreasonable number of meta tags (bazillions of them), the time/resources difference between the brute-force loop and a more elegant solution will be negligible. But it's still an interesting exercise.

**Edit #1**

Thanks to [Daniel Klein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php#111673), I found this beauty...

```
function preg_grep_keys($pattern, $input, $flags = 0) {
    return array_intersect_key($input, array_flip(preg_grep($pattern, array_keys($input), $flags)));
}
```

Which is used in the following way...

```
$pattern = '/(twitter\:)([\w\d\-\_]+)/';

$twitterList = preg_grep_keys($pattern, $tagsList, $flags = 0);
```

And returns...

```
"twitterList": {
    "twitter:card": "... tag content ...",
    "twitter:description": "... tag content ...",
    "twitter:title": "... tag content ...",
    "twitter:site": "... tag content ...",
    "twitter:image": "... tag content ...",
    "twitter:creator": "... tag content ..."
}
```

What a gem! But, I'm unsure how `array_intersect_key()` and `array_flip()` go about their business. I'm probably still looping over the array. And surely `array_keys()` has to loop over the array?

It looks prettier than the `foreach()` above, anyway.

Comment: No there is no such functionality. You will have to either iterate over the list as you are doing or load the html using a DomDocument and traverse/search (with xpath) the DOM Structure to find the meta tags  you are looking for.

Comment: @AronCederholm I found a prettier solution, that I've added to the question  as an edit. I'm pretty sure it'll still be looping over the array, but it's a lot cleaner.

Comment: @Birrel If `edit 1` is a solution you should move it to an answer. `[\w\d\-\_]+` can be simplified to `[-\w]+`, these are the same.

Answer (score 2):

No there is no such functionality, as get_meta_tags() is not designed for this (and certainly was designed prior to Twitter introducing their own set of meta tags).

You will have to either iterate over the list as you are doing (or use array_map() as you also mention yourself) or load the html using a DomDocument and traverse/search (with xpath) the DOM Structure to find the meta tags you are looking for.

In fact, the `twitter:description` naming scheme is just a naming scheme chosen by Twitter. It is not an actual namespace, nor is the tags part of any standard. If you want php to support this functionality of get_meta_tags you can try to [propose it as a feature to add](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/voting#proposal_initiation)

Comment: Bummer. I found a *cleaner* solution - that I've added to the original question as an edit - but I'm pretty sure it'll still be looping through the array, behind the scenes.

Comment: That was a beautiful solution, but it will still iterate over the array. preg_grep will iterate over the array of meta tags. The only way to avoid iterating over this array afterwards is by doing the check during parse time, which means you will have to setup a DomDocument, which won't be any faster.